# Errors while installing ros-groovy on beablebone with ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros, beaglebone, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying hard to install ROS groovy from the source on a beaglebone board which has installed the Ubuntu 12.10 by following the the instructions on this page: http:// ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source

Everything was working well until it got some errors with building the catkin Packages as cited below. I would therefore be grateful to receive some suggestions on how you propose to solve this problem.

Regards,
b4llb0t

Partial output of the terminal (the complete terminal output is available at http:// pastebin.com/LbTPaXYU):

```
$ wstool init src -j8 packages http:// packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/ros_comm
```

....

```
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>[/vcstools]
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>[/vcstools]
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>[/vcstools]
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'rosconsole' : [rosconsole] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/rosconsole/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-rosconsole-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole failed.
Error processing 'catkin' : [catkin] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release/archive/release/catkin/0.5.63.tar.gz version catkin-release-release-catkin-0.5.63 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin failed.
Error processing 'genmsg' : [genmsg] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/genmsg-release/archive/release/genmsg/0.4.17.tar.gz version genmsg-release-release-genmsg-0.4.17 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/genmsg failed.
Error processing 'rosbash' : [rosbash] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/rosbash/1.9.42.tar.gz version ros-release-release-rosbash-1.9.42 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosbash failed.
Error processing 'roslib' : [roslib] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/roslib/1.9.42.tar.gz version ros-release-release-roslib-1.9.42 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/roslib failed.
Error processing 'roscreate' : [roscreate] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/roscreate/1.9.42.tar.gz version ros-release-release-roscreate-1.9.42 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscreate failed.
Error processing 'roslang' : [roslang] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/roslang/1.9.42.tar.gz version ros-release-release-roslang-1.9.42 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/roslang failed.
Error processing 'roscpp' : [roscpp] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/roscpp/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-roscpp-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp failed.
Error processing 'topic_tools' : [topic_tools] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/topic_tools/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-topic_tools-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/topic_tools failed.
Error processing 'rostest' : [rostest] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/rostest/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-rostest-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rostest failed.
Error processing 'rosbag' : [rosbag] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/rosbag/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-rosbag-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosbag failed.
Error processing 'rosmsg' : [rosmsg] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/rosmsg/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-rosmsg-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosmsg failed.
Error processing 'std_msgs' : [std_msgs] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/std_msgs-release/archive/release/std_msgs/0.5.7.tar.gz version std_msgs-release-release-std_msgs-0.5.7 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/std_msgs failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'rosconsole' : [rosconsole] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/rosconsole/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-rosconsole-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole failed.
Error processing 'catkin' : [catkin] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release/archive/release/catkin/0.5.63.tar.gz version catkin-release-release-catkin-0.5.63 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin failed.
Error processing 'genmsg' : [genmsg] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/genmsg-release/archive/release/genmsg/0.4.17.tar.gz version genmsg-release-release-genmsg-0.4.17 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/genmsg failed.
Error processing 'rosbash' : [rosbash] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/rosbash/1.9.42.tar.gz version ros-release-release-rosbash-1.9.42 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosbash failed.
Error processing 'roslib' : [roslib] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/roslib/1.9.42.tar.gz version ros-release-release-roslib-1.9.42 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/roslib failed.
Error processing 'roscreate' : [roscreate] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/roscreate/1.9.42.tar.gz version ros-release-release-roscreate-1.9.42 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscreate failed.
Error processing 'roslang' : [roslang] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/roslang/1.9.42.tar.gz version ros-release-release-roslang-1.9.42 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/roslang failed.
Error processing 'roscpp' : [roscpp] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/roscpp/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-roscpp-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp failed.
Error processing 'topic_tools' : [topic_tools] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/topic_tools/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-topic_tools-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/topic_tools failed.
Error processing 'rostest' : [rostest] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/rostest/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-rostest-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rostest failed.
Error processing 'rosbag' : [rosbag] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/rosbag/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-rosbag-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosbag failed.
Error processing 'rosmsg' : [rosmsg] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/rosmsg/1.9.41.tar.gz version ros_comm-release-release-rosmsg-1.9.41 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosmsg failed.
Error processing 'std_msgs' : [std_msgs] Checkout of https:// github.com/ros-gbp/std_msgs-release/archive/release/std_msgs/0.5.7.tar.gz version std_msgs-release-release-std_msgs-0.5.7 into /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/std_msgs failed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58478/errors-while-installing-ros-groovy-on-beablebone-with-ubuntu-12.10/) by [b4ll-b0t](https://answers.ros.org/users/4459/b4ll-b0t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From looking at the full output, it looks like most packages downloaded successfully, and a few failed.

Try running with -j1 instead of -j8; I suspect that your system can't handle the load of running 8 simultaneous downloads.

You may also want to consult the [ARM Installation](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM) and [Raspbian Installation](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source) instructions, since your system is ARM, and most of the tweaks required to install on Raspberry Pi also apply to other ARM systems.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b4ll-b0t](https://answers.ros.org/users/4459/b4ll-b0t/) on 2013-03-19**:
I don't think what you suggested before was the main issue since I got the following output with ifconfig and ping http://pastebin.com/iFXHqdXP . In addition, if it helps, the complete terminal output is available at http://pastebin.com/LbTPaXYU

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-03-19**:
The complete output is quite helpful; thanks! It looks like your internet connection is working, and only a few packages failed; probably due to high load somewhere.

**Comment by [b4ll-b0t](https://answers.ros.org/users/4459/b4ll-b0t/) on 2013-03-20**:
Thank you very much for the extra information. Apropos, it worked very well with $ wstool init src -j1 packages http:// packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/ros_comm